# how to change directory to a local drive ..in terminal?

Tags: c++, cd-command

i am a new Linux Ubuntu user. I want to save my c++ programs in a local drive. I know how to change directory and mkdir in terminal but i don't know how to switch local drives.

Answer (score 0):

to change your current position to local drives or partitions in NTFS file format within the terminal.first open the terminal ctrl+alt+t and then follow following commands

$ cd /media
$ ls
check here for your user name and use change directoy command to move in your user name folder

$ cd /media/user-name

(again do list command and see all your local drive will be there)

I hope it will solve your query.

Comment: thanks for your instant reply....but it said no such file or directory...

Comment: do your local drives shows in left panel of nautilus file manager?

Comment: Maybe you could use `mount` to see what is mounted and then `cd` to the mounted drive.  You may need to mount the drive.